# Tessellation in DirectX 11 and in OpenGL, what and how?

Tags: opengl, directx, directx-11

DirectX 11 supports tessellation. What is the real purpose of this feature?

And how to determine whether it's working or not on applications built with DX11 or OpenGL?

Answer (score 3):

There are many fields where tessellation could be applied.
for example, Level of detail on a face, this could make you have 2-3 milion triangles without any super load on the gpu when you are up close to the face. that way you achive über graphics.

another way of using it could be the terrain, DICE uses it on their terrain system to enhance the overall look of the terrain to get it more relaistic. 
http://publications.dice.se/publications.asp?show_category=yes&which_category=Rendering

So basicly it´s one of the dx11 best feautres, giving you realy realy good controll of adding extra polygons to meshes. (Higher detail, more good looking graphics)